# Wann wird nach "gemäß" ein Substantiv mit Artikel und wann ohne verwendet?

Tags: word-usage, difference, preposition

Öfters sieht man in Texten, dass nach "gemäß" entweder Substantiv mit einem Artikel oder ohne kommt.

Als Beispiel wäre z.B.

> gemäß der Aussage von...

oder

> gemäß Aussage von ...

Welche Form der wäre hier richtig?
Wann verwendet man die Form mit einem Artikel und wann ohne?

Comment: Übrigens findet man manchmal die Präposition _gemäß_ fälschlicherweise auch mit dem Genitiv („gemäß des Befehls“); richtig muss hier allerdings der Dativ stehen („gemäß dem Befehl“).

Comment: @Loong genau, das ist einer von 3 Fällen, die mir bekannt sind, bei denen viele Leute instinktiv den Genitiv verwenden, obwohl der Dativ korrekt ist, in Umkehrung der ansonsten weit verbreiteten Unsitte von "wegen dem". Die anderen beiden Fälle sind "laut" und "entsprechend".

Answer (score 3):

Im Grunde ist "gemäß" eine ganz normale, wenn auch seltene Präposition. Das heißt, ihre Nomen tragen den Artikel, wenn sie ihn auch anderswo tragen wúrden, und umgekehrt.

Allerdings tritt sie besonders häufig im juristischen Kontext auf: "gemäß Paragraph 113 des StGB", "gemäß Verordnung vom 21.5.1973", etc. In diesen Konstruktionen sind die Nomen oft juristische Regelwerke, die auch sonst keine Artikel tragen: "Artikel 1 der Verfassung sagt ausdrücklich..." Daher hat sich eine Assoziation zwischen dem "gemäß" und dem Fortfall des Artikels entwickelt, so daß nun auch andere Nomen im juristischen Kontext häufiger den Artikel verlieren, als sie es vielleicht sonst täten: "gemäß Aussage von...".

(Solche Entwicklungen, die von einzelnen besonders häufigen Verwendungen auf das gesamte Verhalten eines Lexems übergreifen, sind von der kognitiven Linguistik vielfach beschrieben worden, siehe z.B. Joan Bybee: *Language Change*.)